# Change base directory in Apache application

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Is there an easy way to change the 'base' directory of Apache?  At the moment, I have a tool running and the 'home' page shows up at http://servername.com.  I would like for everything to be moved to http://servername.com/portal.

Example:

```
www.servername.com/portal/directories
www.servername.com/portal/images
etc...
```

I have been able to do this (sort of) with a Redirect:

```
Redirect /portal http://servername.com
```

but I would really like for it to appear that http://servername.com/ does not exist and instead has to be accessed via http://servername.com/portal/ - as opposed to just redirecting /portal/* to /*.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to actually move all the code into the `portal` directory, and redirect all traffic arriving at the root such that it is shunted to the portal.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^/$  /portal/  [R]
```

or

```
RedirectMatch  ^/$  http://servername.com/portal/
```

See [Apache Docs: Moved DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#moveddocroot)